# Image instant uploading isn't working

Tags: camera, google-plus, google-plus-photos

Ever since I upgraded my Google+ app on Friday (3.3.0.40049528) one of my favorite features, Image Instant Upload, is not working.

One of the big changes in [this release](http://gplusproject.appspot.com/tis-the-season-for-shipping) was that instant upload could now upload full size images, rather than limiting them to 2048px.

- I have plenty of available storage (4GB out of 5GB available)
- I have force stopped the Google+ app as well as cleared the data at least once
- The phone (Verizon Galaxy Nexus) has been restarted a couple of times
- I am using the stock camera app for my testing
- The settings were not changed when I updated Google+, but I have confirmed that Instant Upload is set to allow photo uploads on wifi as well as mobile data. I do not have "upload only when charging" turned on, and there is plenty of battery available.

Any ideas? Have I got a bug that needs an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Settings->Accounts and Sync->Your Google Account` make sure Google Photos is selected

This is in `Settings->Google` in 4.x.

EDIT: I just checked, and reinstalling the Google+ all fixed this. Uninstall the app, then install it again.

You then need to go into the settings menu and enable instant upload.

Comment: Google Photos was already checked for syncing.

Comment: You should also have an `Instant Upload` option for syncing. If you do not, like I did not, you should reinstall the app and it will show.

Comment: I do, and it's checked.

Comment: Things seem to be working now, although I'm not sure exactly why. I didn't uninstall the app updates, but I believe that that would have solved my problem. I don't know exactly what did, but your answer makes the most sense to me, which is why I've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was selecting the "Upload all" option under the Google+ settings for Instant Upload. This uploaded some photos that hadn't already been uploaded and seems to have kick-started the process.